# Гондола — ударение при склонении

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, поэзия

> Но плещут в нем те пламенные бури,
>   Но вьются в нем те голубые вихри,
>   Которые потом звучали мне
>   В сиянье солнца, в плеске черных гондол,
>   В летучей тени голубя и в красной
>   Струе вина.

Ударение гóндол — это правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, поэтическая вольность. В том же стихотворении у Ходасевича есть еще два-три случая подобных эрративов: "залитАя", "в тЕни"...